# NEST not able to find documents that elastic search can find

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nest

This is how I search for a document, but it doesn't return any results:

```
var results = ElasticClient.Search<ClusterInstance>(body => body
    .AllIndices()
    .Size(500)
    .Query(query => query
        .QueryString(qs => qs.Query("MyTestName"))
    )
);
resultobject.clusterinstances = results.Documents.ToList();
```

When I use this as a search query in Elasticsearch, I get the results (2 of them) I need.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "MyTestName"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}
```

ElasticClient creation:

```
private static ElasticClient ElasticClient
{
    get
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200")
        return new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(uri));
    }
}
```

Indexing:

```
foreach (var cluster in db.ClusterInstances.Where(a => a.Active.Equals(true)))
{
    client.Index(cluster, "cmdbcli", "clusters", cluster.ClusterInstanceID);
}
```

Version: NEST - Elasticsearch Client 0.12.0 (NuGet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Chris Mantle is correct that the queries don't quite match they should be almost functionally equivalent.

Your search is doing a search on `/_all/clusterinstances/_search` what you probably want is:

```
.Search(s=>s
    .AllIndices()
    .AllTypes()
    ...
```

or

```
.Search(s=>s
    .AllIndices()
    .Type("clusters")
    ...
```

NEST by default infers the the elasticsearch type by lowercasing and pluralizing the CLR Typename.

If you setup your connectionsettings like this:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri)
    .SetDefaultIndex("cmdbcli")
    .MapDefaultTypeNames(d=>d
       .Add(typeof(ClusterInstance), "clusters")
    )
   ....
```

then

```
.Search<ClusterInstance>(s=>s.Query())
```

will default to `/cmdbcli/clusters/_search`

Answer (score 1):

Your queries don't match. The one produced by your code will be a simple `query_string` query, not the `bool` query you define in your JSON query. I think you need to alter your code to produce a similar query to the one you're defining in JSON:

```
var results = ElasticClient
    .Search<ClusterInstance>(body => body
        .AllIndices()
        .Size(500)
        .Query(query => query
            .Bool(@bool => @bool
                .Must(must => must
                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                        .Query("MyTestName"))))));

resultobject.clusterinstances = results.Documents.ToList();
```